# lftp issues with large directory: ls & mv

Tags: lftp

I have been backing up files from a CCTV camera to an FTP directory without really thinking about it for about 6 months, and inadvertently created a directory with what might be 100,000 files in it.

This week I've decided to do something about it, as now whenever I run the backup script it stalls for 30 minutes while it downloads the filelist needed for the `mirror` operation.

My first action was to create a small script to use `ls` to echo all of the filenames in that directory to a file. I then ran that file through google sheets to extract sub-portions of the file name from which to create more managable sub-folders. When I then made the test script below to move the first file I get `mv: Access failed: 501 File not found (ARC20170315113818.mp4)`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# @description: attempt to move file to new folder

#FTP login details
HOST=####
USER=####
PASSWORD=####

lftp -u "$USER","$PASSWORD" $HOST << EOF


cd /CCTVArchive/V2/192.168.0.24/webdav/sdcard/alarm

mv ARC20170314180647.mp4 2017/03/14/



bye

EOF
```

Is there a reason why `ls` and `mv` would have a different opinion on what files exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message related to the target directory for the move not existing! Once I've prefaced the `mv` commands with the appropriate number of `mkdir` commands they all work as expected.